# Using GCM how to know message is arrived or not in the device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I use `Google Cloud Messaging` service to push the message from my 3rd party app server to the `android` device.  I go through [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) to implement GCM service in my platform . I follow all the steps shown over there.

After creating **Gcm-demo-client** client application as mention over [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)  , Below are the step which i follow:

1. Install Gcm-demo-client into my android device.
2. Register device with GCM Server.
3. Receive the Registration Id successfully.
4. Send message from my 3rd party application server to [here](https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send). It gives me status 200 OK. It means message successfully sent to my registered android device.

But , Device does not able to receive any message . So how can i know that the message is arrived or not when application is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to receive messages using GCM now . My mistake is that i work on the project of Gcm-demo-client . So there are some stuffs of their own . But what i do is i create new android project and implement from starting . Its working now.